# List files starting with given name in subdirectories R

Tags: r

I have a directory containing 70 other sub-directories with different CSV files. CSV files in each directory look like this *Modified2-3.csv*, *added2_3.csv*, *Retired4_5.csv*. My end result is to join all CSV starting with the name Modified but before that How can I loop through all subdirectories selecting only files starting with **modified**

I have tried this method but it says the character is zero

```
list.files(pattern = "^Modified.*name.csv")
```

I do want my result is a list of modified CSV looking like this  *Modified2_3.csv*, *Modified3_4.csv*,*Modified7_8.csv*

Comment: `"^Modified.*\\.csv$"` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736/learning-regular-expressions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to go through them without a loop with the use of list.files()'s recursive argument.

```
list.files(pattern = "^Modified", recursive=TRUE)
```